# Why after implementing get in field property I can't initialize that field in constructor?

Tags: c#, constructor, compiler-errors, initialization, getter-setter

I am doing tutorial from MSDN and I was following it step by step, after implementing get method in Balance property I got an error in constructor when I try to initialize that field:

*error CS0200: Unable to assign value to property or indexer "BankAccount.Balance" - it is read only*

If I good interprets it tells me that I do not have set method in property. But why i can initialize Number field if it also do not have set method.

Here is code:

```
public class BankAccount{
    private static int accountNumberSeed = 1234567890;

    public string Number {get;}
    public string Owner {get; set;}

    public decimal Balance{
        get{
            decimal balance = 0;
            foreach (var item in allTransactions){
                balance += item.Amount;
            }

            return balance;
        }

    }

    public BankAccount(string name, decimal initialBalance){
        this.Owner = name;
        this.Balance = initialBalance;
        this.Number = accountNumberSeed.ToString();
        ++accountNumberSeed;
    }

    private List<Transaction> allTransactions = new List<Transaction>();

    public void MakeDeposit(decimal amount, DateTime date, string note){
        if (amount <= 0){
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(amount), "Amount of deposit must be positive");
        }
        var deposit = new Transaction(amount, date, note);
        allTransactions.Add(deposit);    
    }

    public void MakeWithdrawal(decimal amount, DateTime date, string note){ }


}
```

Comment: Your `Balance` property *computes* the value from `allTransactions`. What would you expect to be assigned? How would you expect that to be relevant when the property is fetched?

Comment: For a property implementation, using just `{get;}` is a special case which tells the compiler to introduce a hidden private backing field for that property, and also to allow the constructor to set the property. If you use an implementation of `get` which does more than that, no private backing field is automatically generated and there is therefore no way to set a value for that property in the constructor.

Comment: @JonSkeet ok thanks, I understand. So the soulution for this may be making deposit in constructor for the amount of initialize balance.

Comment: Either that, or have a separate "initial balance" field that you use as the starting value of the `balance` local variable in the `Balance` property.